# NetBeans do not compile openGL project

Tags: qt, opengl, netbeans, mingw, msys

I am programming in Netbeans, using MSYS, Qt, mingw and openGL and want to know how to solve linker problems.

myWindow.h

```
#ifndef _MYWINDOW_H
#define _MYWINDOW_H

#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>

class myWindow : public QGLWidget{
public:
    myWindow(QGLWidget* parent = 0);
private:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int  h);
    void drawCircle(int tr_x, int tr_y, float size);
};

#endif  /* _MYWINDOW_H */
```

myWindow.cpp

```
#include "myWindow.h"
#include <QtGui/QtGui>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

myWindow::myWindow(QGLWidget* parent):QGLWidget(parent){
    setWindowTitle("lab1");
}

GLfloat circle[20][2] = {
{1, 0}, {0.951057, 0.309017}, {0.809017, 0.587785}, {0.587786, 0.809017},
{0.309018, 0.951056}, {0, 1}, {-0.309016, 0.951057}, {-0.587784, 0.809018},
{-0.809016, 0.587787}, {-0.951056, 0.309019},{-1, 0}, {-0.951057, -0.309014},
{-0.809019, -0.587783}, {-0.587788, -0.809015}, {-0.30902, -0.951055}, {0, -1},
{0.309013, -0.951058}, {0.587782, -0.80902}, {0.809014, -0.587789}, {0.951055, -0.309021}};

void myWindow::initializeGL(){
   qglClearColor(Qt::gray); 
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
   glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}

void myWindow::paintGL(){
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   //glScalef(2, 2, 1);

   qglColor(Qt::white);

   renderText(-50, 150 , 0, QString::fromUtf8("This is a snowman!!!"), QFont());

   qglColor(Qt::black);
   drawCircle(10, 75, 3); //eye1
   drawCircle(-10, 75, 3); // eye2

   glLineWidth(3.0f);
   qglColor(Qt::red);
   glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex2f(-10, 60);
      glVertex2f(0, 55);
      glVertex2f(0, 55);
      glVertex2f(10, 60);
   glEnd();

   glLineWidth(5.0f);
   qglColor(Qt::black);
   glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex2f(-70, 10);
      glVertex2f(-38, 5);

      glVertex2f(38, 5);
      glVertex2f(70, 10);
   glEnd();

   qglColor(Qt::green);
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex2f(-15, 120);
      glVertex2f(-20, 90);
      glVertex2f(20, 90);
      glVertex2f(15, 120);
   glEnd();

   QColor white(255, 255, 255, 255);
   qglColor(white);
   drawCircle(0, 65, 30);
   drawCircle(0, 0, 40);
   drawCircle(0, -85, 50);

   glFlush();
}

void myWindow::resizeGL(int w, int h){
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();

   gluOrtho2D(-w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2);
   // Update OpenGL viewport and internal variables
   glViewport(0,0,w,h);
}

void myWindow::drawCircle(int tr_x, int tr_y, float size){
    int i;

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            glVertex2f(circle[i][0]*size+tr_x, circle[i][1]*size+tr_y);
    glEnd();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "myWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    myWindow win;
    win.show();

    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

NetBeans output:

```
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Galym/Documents/NetBeansProjects/qt'
/C/Qt/4.8.0/bin/qmake.exe VPATH=. -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
mv -f qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.mk
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/qt-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/qt.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Galym/Documents/NetBeansProjects/qt'
g++.exe -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include/QtCore' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include/QtGui' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include/ActiveQt' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/mkspecs/default' -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o myWindow.cpp
g++.exe -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include/QtCore' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include/QtGui' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/include/ActiveQt' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/Qt/4.8.0/mkspecs/default' -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
windres -i qt_resource.rc -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/qt_resource_res.o --include-dir=. -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/qt.exe build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o  -L'c:/Qt/4.8.0/lib' -lmingw32 -lqtmaind build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/qt_resource_res.o -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o: In function `myWindow':
C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:13: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QGLWidgetC2EP7QWidgetPKS_6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:15: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QGLWidgetD2Ev'
C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:13: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QGLWidgetC2EP7QWidgetPKS_6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:15: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QGLWidgetD2Ev'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:25: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9QGLWidget13qglClearColorERK6QColor'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:38: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9QGLWidget8qglColorERK6QColor'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:40: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QGLWidget10renderTextEdddRK7QStringRK5QFonti'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:42: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9QGLWidget8qglColorERK6QColor'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:47: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9QGLWidget8qglColorERK6QColor'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:56: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9QGLWidget8qglColorERK6QColor'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:65: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9QGLWidget8qglColorERK6QColor'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.cpp:74: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK9QGLWidget8qglColorERK6QColor'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x8): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::metaObject() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0xc): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::qt_metacast(char const*)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x10): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x1c): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::event(QEvent*)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x54): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::paintEngine() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x84): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x8c): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0xe8): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::updateGL()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0xec): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::updateOverlayGL()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0xfc): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::initializeOverlayGL()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x100): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::resizeOverlayGL(int, int)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x104): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::paintOverlayGL()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x108): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::glInit()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x10c): undefined reference to `QGLWidget::glDraw()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o:myWindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV8myWindow[vtable for myWindow]+0x124): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QGLWidget::paintEngine() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/myWindow.o: In function `~myWindow':
C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.h:13: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QGLWidgetD2Ev'
C:\Users\Galym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\qt/myWindow.h:13: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QGLWidgetD2Ev'
collect2: РІС‹РїРѕР»РЅРµРЅРёРµ ld Р·Р°РІРµСЂС€РёР»РѕСЃСЊ СЃ РєРѕРґРѕРј РІРѕР·РІСЂР°С‚Р° 1
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/qt.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Galym/Documents/NetBeansProjects/qt'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Galym/Documents/NetBeansProjects/qt'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 7s)
```

Environment variable PATH = C:\mingw\bin;C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you're not including the `QtOpenGL` module in your compilation (or more specifically, linking) process.

If you're using `.pro` files for your project, you would need to add `QT += opengl` to it, to tell `qmake` that you're using `QtOpenGL`. Other build systems might need you to do different things.

When using NetBeans to manage the configuration, if you go into the Project properties, under Build -> Qt, there should be checkboxes for the various Qt modules, including `QtOpenGL`. Here you can enable/disable the linking to any of the Qt modules.

Comment: in the NetBeans, There is no .pro file, and I do not know how to add this statement to this file

Comment: Based on the output, it would appear that it *does* use `qmake` and a `.pro` file `nbproject/qt-Debug.pro`, at least internally. If you go into the project's properties, under Build -> Qt, there should be checkboxes for the various Qt modules, including `QtOpenGL`.

Comment: This have saved me hours of debugging! Thank you!